# find a number x whose bitwise AND with the power of 2 is always false

Tags: javascript, math, bit-manipulation

How do I find a number x whose bitwise AND with the power of 2 is always false (exclude 1)

```
if(x & 2){
  console.log("true");
}else {
console.log("false");
}
```

Comment: What is "the power of 2"? Your code just shows `2` in which case `x` can be any number that satisifies either `x % 4 === 0` or `x % 4 === 1`. EG. any of `0,1,4,5,8,9,12,13,16,17...`

Comment: yes x &2,x&4.....x&2^n @Paulpro

Comment: You want to find an `x` where that is zero all powers of two? The only answers are `0` and (JavaScript specific) multiples of `4294967296`. (`0`, `4294967296`, `8589934592`, `12884901888`, ...)

Comment: And how did you derive that? @Paulpro

Comment: Those are the only integers that have zeroes in all of the lower 32 bit positions, which are all the bit positions you can check with an `&` operator in JavaScript.

Comment: Great!Thanks a lot @Paulpro

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried like this?

```js
var alwaysTrue = [];
var alwaysFalse = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    if (i & Math.pow(i, 2)) {
        alwaysTrue.push(i)
    } else {
        alwaysFalse.push(i)
    }
}
console.log(`Always True ${alwaysTrue}`);
console.log(`Always False ${alwaysFalse}`);
```

Comment: @art see my edit. Is that something you want. Just run the code snippet